# D3.js v3 add nodes into boxes?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I use the http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292 example to build a network graph. The network exists of all my applications used. Now I want to add the applications into a hosts rectangle to show on which host they are running.

Can someone guide me into the right direction, I read over the different [layouts documentations](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/API-Reference.md#d3layout-layouts) but didn't find a clue how to combine the force layout with multiple objects-hierarchies. Can someone help me?

Sketch* of what I want:

```
|-------       |-------       |-------
| hostA |      | hostB |      | hostB |
| ===== |      | ===== |      | ===== |
| appA --------->appB---------->appC  |
|---↑---|      |       |   ↑  |       |
    |          | appD------|  | appE  |       
    |          |---↓---|      |-------|
    |              |
    |--------------|

* Whereas app? are circles bigger as more connections they have
```

Comment: You just want a rectangle with two text elements in it to represent your node?

Comment: Yes but I want multiple app circle nodes inside it.

Comment: @Mark I updated the Graph to express my idea a bit more. Does it help explaining my problem? How can I have "two" nodes using force layout - the apps and the hosts?